# Question about the cell cycle

Tags: biology

A diploid cell in G1 has 6 chromosomes. How many chromosomes and how many chromatids are present in each of the following stages?

Here is what I am guessing

G1: 6 chromosomes ;  6 chromatids
G2: 6 chromosomes ; 12 chromatids
Prophase: 6 chromosomes; 12 chromatids
Metaphase: 6 chromosomes; 12 chromatids
Anaphase: 12 chromosomes; 12 chromatids
Telophase: 12 chromosomes; 12 chromatids

Comment: This might be better suited for http://biology.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, your guess is right!